# Construction of generic type parameter in Haxe

Tags: constructor, haxe, generic-type-argument

I'm trying to instantiate a class based on a function type parameter.
Although the [documentation](http://haxe.org/manual/type-system-generic-type-parameter-construction.html) says it is possible, I can't make it work.

Consider the following code:

```
// Dialog base class
// Every dialog in my application will derive from this
class Dialog
{
    public function new()
    {
        // do some stuff here
    }
}

// One of the possible dialogs in the application
// Extends Dialog
class TestDialog extends Dialog
{
    public function new()
    {
        super();
        // do some more stuff
    }
}

// A simple class that tries to instantiate a specialized dialog, like TestDialog 
class SomeAppClass
{
    public function new() 
    {
        var instance = create(TestDialog);
    }

    @:generic
    function create<T:Dialog>(type:Class<T>):T
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

This doesn't work with the following error:
`create.T does not have a constructor`

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong, but what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SpecialDialog` could have a different *constructor* than `Dialog`.
So you have to **constraint it** and then also constraint to `Dialog`.

[Code @ Try Haxe](http://try.haxe.org/#7668b)

```
package;


typedef Constructible = {
  public function new():Void;
}


// Dialog base class
// Every dialog in my application will derive from this
class Dialog
{
    public function new()
    {
        trace("dialog");
    }
}


class SuperDialog extends Dialog
{
    public function new()
    {
        super();
        trace("super dialog");
    }
}

// A simple class that tries to instantiate a specialized dialog, like TestDialog 

class SomeAppClass
{
    public function new() 
    {
        var dialog = create(Dialog);
        var superDialog = create(SuperDialog);
    }

    @:generic
    public static function create<T:(Constructible,Dialog)>(type:Class<T>):T
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

class Test {
  static public function main() {
    new SomeAppClass();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it means that I MUST have a typedef as a constraint?

Comment: A typedef telling the compiler the structure for the constructor you will use.

Comment: I can't understand why I need this typedef at all... A class (IMHO) should be enough to tell the compiler what is what. Anyways, thank you.